# Insertar input date en variable JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo un problema con los input date, al intentar meterlos en una variable no funciona o falla, y no logro hacer que se inserte correctamente.

Este fue mi intento propio

```
function sub() {
    date = document.getElementById("date").value;
    alert(date);
};
```

```
<body>
    <input type="date" id="date">
    <button onclick="sub()">Prueba</button>
</body>
```

Despues de buscar una ayuda en MDN lo intente de la siguiente forma:

```
function sub() {
    var date = document.querySelector('input[type="date"]');
    alert(date);
};
```

Mismo HTML

Y en ninguno de los casos conseguí que se metiera en la variable. No me importa si es un Array, una línea de texto seguida o son necesarias varias variables para cada dato... pero alguien sabe como hacerlo?
Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿que estas intentado hacer? ¿obtener el valor del input o dibujar un nuevo input?

Comment: Estoy intentando obtener el valor del input del date, ya que necesito los 3 números de la fecha para trabajar con ellos, por eso no me importa si hay que hacerlo con Arrays o algo del estilo

Comment: Yo he probado tú código y si me funciona, me saca la fecha que le pongo. He probado el primero de la ID

Comment: En serio?? Lol pues a mi no me va...
no me aparece el alert y si lo hago con console.log no aparece linea de comando

Comment: De hecho no es que no me aparezca el alert... si sale pero con el mensaje:

[object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: Por saber si es temas de compatibilidades, que JS funciona como quiere... que navegador usaste para probarlo?

Comment: dentro de la funcion sub, reemplaza la variable con esto var date = document.querySelector('input[type="date"]').value;

Comment: He probado tu codigo y funciona correctamente, verifica y dinos si es que nos falta algo? te dejo el ejecutable https://jsfiddle.net/1Lfhmnuz/

Comment: Ivandez lo que tu dices tambien lo probé y no funcionaba,

Y efectivamente con jsfiddle si que funciona bien... Entonces no entiendo por qué es que ejecutandolo directamente desde el .html no me funciona

Comment: Curiosamente ejecutandolo desde el mismo archivo en vez de un .js aparte si que funciona bien, no creo que sea que lo he vinculdo mal porque lo comprobe y si estaba bien vinculado... En fin mientras miro a ver como arreglo este problema lo pongo en el mismo archivo todo y listo... gracias por la ayuda